# Custom field being assigned during account insert is coming up null in custom object trigger test

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object, after-trigger

I am trying to test a new check added to a custom object trigger (`if (!String.isBlank(ap.Patient__r.ExternalId__c))`). When running the test, ExternalId__c is coming up null. It is being assigned when the account is inserted from a TestHelper class I have created. the Patient__c is a lookup field on the AuthorizedPerson__c object that points to the account created in the test.

Trigger:

```
trigger trg_AfterAuthorizedPersonChange on AuthorizedPerson__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {
    System.debug('Entering trigger trg_AfterAuthorizedPersonChange ');
    System.debug('Current Request URL ' + String.valueOf(URL.getCurrentRequestUrl()));
    if (!Test.isRunningTest()){
        if (String.valueOf(URL.getCurrentRequestUrl()).toLowerCase().contains('services/data')) {
            System.debug('Exiting trigger because it was called from API.');
            return;
        }
    }
    List<Id> patientIds = new List<Id>();
    if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {
        System.debug('Trigger was insert or update');
        for (AuthorizedPerson__c ap : Trigger.new) {
            System.debug('Patient ID ' + ap.Patient__c);
            if (!patientIds.contains(ap.Patient__c)) {
                System.debug('Here is the external ID ### ' + ap.Patient__r.ExternalId__c);
                if (!String.isBlank(ap.Patient__r.ExternalId__c)) {
                    patientIds.add(ap.Patient__c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (Trigger.isDelete) {
        System.debug('Trigger was delete');
        for (AuthorizedPerson__c ap : Trigger.old) {
            System.debug('Patient ID ' + ap.Patient__c);
            if (!patientIds.contains(ap.Patient__c)) {
                if (!String.isBlank(ap.Patient__r.ExternalId__c)) {
                    patientIds.add(ap.Patient__c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.debug('Patient IDs list ' + patientIds.toString());
    if (patientIds.size() > 0) {
        SyncToPatientsDB.Send(patientIds);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@isTest
public class test_AuthorizedPersonTriggers {    
    @isTest
    static void testTrigger(){
        // Set up test data
        
        
        Account PayerAcc = new Account();
        PayerAcc.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Payer').getRecordTypeId();
        PayerAcc.Name = 'Test Payer';
        PayerAcc.MemberStatus__c = 'Enrolled';
        insert PayerAcc; 
        
        Pricebook2 PB = New PriceBook2(Id = test.getStandardPricebookId(), isActive = true, Name = 'Test PB');
        
        Contract PayerCon = new Contract();
        PayerCon.AccountId = PayerAcc.Id;
        PayerCon.StartDate = Date.today();
        PayerCon.ContractTerm = 24;
        PayerCon.Pricebook2Id = PB.Id;
        PayerCon.Status = 'Draft';
        insert PayerCon;
        
        Group__c PayerGroup = new Group__c();
        PayerGroup.Name = 'Test Group';
        PayerGroup.Contract__c = PayerCon.Id;
        PayerGroup.Insurance_Provider__c = PayerAcc.Id;
        insert PayerGroup;
        
        Account PatAcc = TestHelper.CreatePersonAccountInternal(PayerAcc, PayerCon, PayerGroup);
    
        // Test AuthorizedPerson triggers
        AuthorizedPerson__c person = new AuthorizedPerson__c();
        person.Patient__c = PatAcc.id;
        person.FirstName__c = 'Test';
        person.LastName__c = 'Person';
        person.RelationShip__c = 'Family Member';
        person.NotificationTypes__c = 'Monthly Report;Every Check';
        insert person;
        person.FirstName__c = 'Test2';
        update person;
        delete person;
    }
}
```

TestHelper Method:

```
public static Account CreatePersonAccountInternal(Account payerAccount, Contract contract, Group__c group1) {
        // Generate person account object
        Id personRecordId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Person Account').getRecordTypeId();
        Account personAccount = new Account(RecordTypeId = personRecordId, Preferred_Name__c = 'Testy', FirstName = 'Test Patient', LastName = 'Test Name', Payer_Account__c = payerAccount.Id,
                                            Contract__c = contract.Id, Group__c = group1.Id, MemberStatus__c = 'Enrolled', EnrolledDate__c = Date.today(),
                                            PersonBirthdate = Date.newInstance(1999, 09, 09), GenieId__c = '98756', SmartWatchId__c = '23456', PersonEmail = 'n@email.com',
                                            HealthCloudGA__Gender__pc = 'Male', PersonMobilePhone = '1234567890', MailingAddressLine1__pc = 'EG', MailingAddressCity__pc = 'EG',
                                            MailingAddressState__pc = 'EG', MailingAddressCountry__pc = 'USA', PersonMailingStreet = 'EG', PersonMailingCity = 'EG',
                                            PersonMailingState = 'EG', PersonMailingCountry = 'USA', PersonMailingPostalCode = '00000', ShippingStreet = 'EG\nEG\nEG', 
                                            ShippingCity = 'EG', ShippingState = 'EG', ShippingCountry = 'USA', ShippingPostalCode = '00000', MemberID__c = '238476123',
                                            SSN__c = '423554', Skilltrack__c = 'A', WelcomeKitStatus__c ='Shipped', WelcomeKitStatusDate__c = Datetime.Now(), ExternalId__c = '1001');
        insert personAccount; 
        
        return personAccount;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related data is never available in the instances of records that you get from Trigger Context Variables. If you need to use more than one dot/period/full-stop to access the data (as you do with `ap.Patient__r.ExternalId__c`), then you need to explicitly query for it.

Aside from that, you could create a formula field to pull that data into your `AuthorizedPerson__c` records (so you would access the data via `ap.My_Formula_Field__c`)

Comment: Thank you for the info! The custom field works!